# Select information from 3 tables in SQL

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have three tables in a SQLite database: book, author and loaned_books. They look like this
**book:** _id | author_id | title | subject
**author:** _id | first_name | last_name
**loaned_books:** _id | book_id | loan_date | due_date
The author_id is a foreign key for the author table, and the book_id is a foreign key for the book table.

I am trying to create a query that extracts all the books (with their associated author) which are not loaned. So far, I have this query:

```
SELECT book.title, book.subject, author.first_name, author.last_name  
FROM book, author  
INNER JOIN loaned_books ON book._id != loaned_books.book_id AND book.author_id = author._id
```

This one does the job with the exception that all the records returned are duplicated. I have tried using DISTINCT on the column names, but the result is wrong as well.

What would be a query that returns all the books (with their associated author) that are not loaned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you join `book` and `author`:

```
FROM book, author
```

is wrong because it returns the cartesian product of the 2 tables.
 
You need a LEFT JOIN to `loaned_books` and return the non matching rows (meaning the books that don't exists in `loaned_books`)

```
SELECT b.title, b.subject, a.first_name, a.last_name
FROM book AS b
INNER JOIN author AS a ON b.author_id = a._id
LEFT JOIN loaned_books AS l ON b._id = l.book_id
WHERE l._id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try executing this:

`SELECT distinct book.title, book.subject, author.first_name, author.last_name
FROM book inner join author on book.id = author._id left outer join loaned_books ON book._id = loaned_books.book_id where loaned_books.book_id is null or length(loan_date) = 0 or loan_date = ''`

Comment: I tried this query on my database, but it did not work. However, the query from the answer I've accepted above worked perfectly.